# Does parity include a console?

Tags: parity, clients, console, cli

I can run `geth console` to get a command line interface spawned after launching geth. Similar also works for eth.

I tried `parity console` but that didn't work out.

```
 ~ $ parity console
Invalid arguments.

Usage:
  parity daemon <pid-file> [options]
  parity account (new | list) [options]
  parity [options]
```

Is there anything like that available for parity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

running `parity --geth` allows to use `eth attach` or `geth attach` to spawn a console.

Comment: Please note that you do not need to run `parity --geth`. You can attach console to a vanilla parity without geth compatibility mode, at least in 1.6.5.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, it complains: `Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix /Users/jikkujose/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory`. Do I need to specify custom path?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the parity IPC path after `geth attach`.

Answer (score 5):

In March 2016, [Gav Wood wrote:](https://gitter.im/ethcore/parity?at=56e3d81a89dd3cce1005cfa9)

> we don't yet have a javascript interface, however it should be
>   possible to use eth console or geth console to connect to a running
>   parity client

i haven't tried that yet, though...

Answer (score 4):

Not yet possible as this issue [here](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/774) suggests.

`ethconsole` depends on IPC, which will be available as of Civility (1.1).

Answer (score 2):

`geth attach` only lets you use webjs methods at the moment. By using nodejs console with `@parity/api` package you can access parity methods.

Install package globally and launch concole :

```
$ npm install @parity/api
$ node
```

On node console use parity package :

```
>// import the actual Api class
>const Api = require("@parity/api");

>// do the setup
>const provider = new Api.Provider.Http('http://localhost:8545');
>const api = new Api(provider);

// eg. use api.parity.addReservedPeer method
>api.parity.addReservedPeer("enode://d64d5f74b1715c525dc88e87a52eca1574c09593ed29401d205ecfef9fbfe52fa308f966bab3a5966da1bb74212fecdb328cddceb572c38b536c597166784347@203080240034.static.ctinets.com:35423").then((data)=> {console.log(data)})
```