# Parity client from command line

Tags: web3js, parity

Follow up on this post
[Does parity include a console?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/does-parity-include-a-console)

It is possible to have a JS script -with web3 nodejs library- running in a linux machine which only has installed parity as a client (no geth)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.

```
$ npm install web3
$ node test.js
```

... where test.js looks like this:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
console.log(web3.eth.accounts);
```

Comment: thanks! so it does not matter if the client is geth or parity (or other) the web3 will work either way?

Comment: Correct, web3 uses the JSONRPC interface which both clients expose. (See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC)

Comment: Piles, but not that would fit or be appropriate here. But keep an eye on the --geth command-line parameter for parity. I've found that there are issues with gas estimates for contract deployment that only get resolved with you run parity --geth. See https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/2434